# Blind and Visually Impaired Chess Players

Tags: chess-olympiad

Answering this [question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/12368/the-strength-of-blind-chess-players/21305#21305), I was wondering how visually impaired or blind a player should be to participate at the [IBCA Chess Olympiad for Blind and Visually Impaired Chess Players](http://chess-results.com/tnr281869.aspx?lan=1&art=2&rd=1&turdet=YES&flag=30).

Answer (score 1):

Searching the web, I haven't found anything directly answering your question. However, the [rules supplements for blind chess](http://www.ibca-info.org/rules-of-chess.php) apply to games between a sighted player and one who is [legally blind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_impairment#Legal_definition). Thus it seems a safe inference that one would need to be legally blind to participate in IBCA events.